# After compiling the tikz figure shows overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, article

I am having trouble with the following tikz figure. Any help will be appreciated.

Compiling the code below, the following erroneous figure comes:

[image]

```
\pdfminorversion=4
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\documentclass[11pt]{article}  
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} 
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\newif\ifmicrotype
\DeclareOption{microtype}{\microtypetrue} 
\ProcessOptions\relax
\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\tempaa{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
  \ifx\theequation\tempaa
     \def\theequation{\thesection\hbox{--}\arabic{equation}}
  \fi
  \ifmicrotype
     \RequirePackage{microtype}%
     \DeclareMicrotypeAlias{mnt}{ptm}%
  \fi
  \DeclareMathSizes{10}   {10}   {7}{6}
  \DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{10.95}{8}{6}
}



\headsep 23pt
\footskip 35pt
\hoffset -4truemm
\voffset 12.5truemm

\newskip\stdskip                      % 
\stdskip=6.6pt plus3.3pt minus3.3pt    

\setlength{\textheight}{7.5in}          
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.2in}         
\flushbottom                           
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}            
\setlength{\parskip}{\stdskip}
\setlength{\medskipamount}{\stdskip}
\setlength{\mathsurround}{0.8pt}     
\setlength{\labelsep}{0.75em} 
\newcommand{\stdspace}{\hskip 0.75em plus 0.15em \ignorespaces}
\let\qua\stdspace  
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}  
\newcommand{\ppar}{\par\goodbreak\medskip} 
\newcommand{\sh}[1]{\penalty-800\ppar{\bf #1}\par\medskip\nobreak}
\newcommand{\rk}[1]{\ppar{\bf #1}\stdspace}    

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
$$\begin{tikzcd}
{ H_2(\mathbf S', \partial \mathbf S')\cong \mathbb Z} \arrow[d, "\times \deg(f_\text{res})"'] \arrow[rr, "{\large 1\longmapsto \overset{k}{\oplus} 1}"] &  & {\large \overset{k}{\oplus}\mathbb Z\cong H_1(\partial \mathbf S')} \arrow[d, "{\large\overset{k}{\oplus} 1\longmapsto \overset{k}{\oplus} (\pm 1)\bigoplus \overset{3-k}{\oplus} 0}"] \\
{\large H_2(\mathbf P,\partial \mathbf P)\cong \mathbb Z} \arrow[rr, "{\large 1\longmapsto \overset{3}{\oplus}1}"]                                   &  & {\large \overset{3}{\oplus}\mathbb Z\cong H_1(\partial \mathbf P)}                                                     
\end{tikzcd}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Get rid of `\setlength{\mathsurround}{0.8pt} `

Comment: Do you have special reason to use so old LaTeX? If I remove most of your preamble and use recent LaTeX version, it works fine.